# Counting different characters in a large dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I'm looking to count the number of times different words appear in a data frame, and then to remake that into a new data frame that shows the counts for each word.

For example, I have a data table like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Continues... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Passwords1 | GHSME12 | POWDER2 | JOHNC | PLOW01 | PLANE |
| Usercode20 | HUNG1 | GHSME12 | PLOW01 | GORGE09 | JOHNC |
| Usercode15 | PLOW01 | GORGE09 | JOHNC | POWDER2 | SYRUP9 |
| Continues... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to be able to count the number of times each word in the data appears for each Col1. While I could do things such as the number of items WordX = wordX, there are hundreds of passwords, making manual counting difficult, so I wonder if I have to use a for loop and a blank data frame in this situation to achieve something like this:

| Passwords | Passwords1 | Usercode20 | Usercode15 | Continues... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GHSME12 | 1 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| POWDER2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| JOHNC | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| PLOW01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| PLANE | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| HUNG1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| GORGE09 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| SYRUP9 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |

I would appreciate it if someone has a good idea about tackling this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table(cbind(stack(df, -Col1)['values'], df['Col1']))

         Col1
values    Passwords1 Usercode15 Usercode20
  GHSME12          1          0          1
  GORGE09          0          1          1
  HUNG1            0          0          1
  JOHNC            1          1          1
  PLANE            1          0          0
  PLOW01           1          1          1
  POWDER2          1          1          0
  SYRUP9           0          1          0
```

tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(-Col1) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Col1, values_from = name, 
               values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  value   Passwords1 Usercode20 Usercode15
  <chr>        <int>      <int>      <int>
1 GHSME12          1          1          0
2 POWDER2          1          0          1
3 JOHNC            1          1          1
4 PLOW01           1          1          1
5 PLANE            1          0          0
6 HUNG1            0          1          0
7 GORGE09          0          1          1
8 SYRUP9           0          0          1
```

Comment: It looks like the code worked, but it made three columns, first being the values, the second being a repeated list of either Passwords1, Usercode15, and Usercode20, then the third column being the counts. How could I adjust that code to make it that each individual category (Passwords1, Usercode15, and Usercode20) becomes its own separate column? Thanks!

Comment: @powdermonkey you are directly converting the `table` into `data.frame`. To do so, use `as.data.frame.matrix(table(cbind(stack(df, -Col1)['values'], df['Col1']))`. Otherwise use the second code